# Code Coverage on Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, code-coverage

I'm seeing a pattern throughout my code where the lambda expression is showing as not covered in code coverage, the debugger DOES step through the code and there are no conditional blocks.

```
public CollectionModel()
{
    List<Language> languages = LanguageService.GetLanguages();
    this.LanguageListItems =
        languages.Select(
            s =>
            new SelectListItem { Text = s.Name, Value = s.LanguageCode, Selected = false }). // <-- this shows as not covered
            AsEnumerable();
}
```

It is somewhat odd.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think you mean is that the debugger is not stepping over the indicated line; is that right?

If that's your question, then the answer is that, at least in this particular case, what you are seeing is **deferred execution**. All of the LINQ extension methods provided by [`System.Linq.Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) exhibit this behavior: namely, the code inside the lambda statement itself is *not* executed on the line where you are defining it. The code is only executed once the resulting object is enumerated over.

Add this beneath the code you have posted:

```
foreach (var x in this.LanguageListItems)
{
    var local = x;
}
```

Here, you will see the debugger jump back to your lambda.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, he couly use `ToList` instead of `AsEnumerable` and have the same effect.

Comment: @nikie: Yeah, but I wanted him specifically to see the debugger jump back to the lambda upon iteration as I feel that makes it unmistakably clear what's going on.

Comment: Note also that if the collection is empty then the projection will never be called even if the collection is iterated.

Comment: the debugger DOES step through this.  Which is why its so confusing.  My company wants us to use AsEnuerable instead of list for some reason.

Comment: you guys are absolutely right..  The code executes propertly when enumerated with ToList()

Comment: We actually uncovered a particular nasty bug in the .net framework.  Apparently using Code Contracts with Lambda Expressions will show the code as covered, but will not show as 100% complete.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making the unit tests, if you have a method that returns the list you described as LanguageListItems, you can do this in the unit test:

```
var result = await controller.SomeAction();
var okObjectResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
var results = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IEnumerable<YourDtoClass>>okObjectResult.Value);
Assert.NotNull(results);
Assert.All(results, dto => Assert.NotNull(dto.PendingItemCount));
Assert.All(results, dto => Assert.NotNull(dto.ApprovedItemCount));
```

Each Assert of any of the dto's property will execute the lambda expression and then it will appear as covered.