# VS Code Coverage won't recognize only possible Expression Lambda Path

Tags: linq, visual-studio, unit-testing, lambda, code-coverage

I have following Extension Method which is just a negation of Linq.Any()

[image]

These two UnitTests do test it completely

```
[TestMethod]
public void EnumerableExtensions_None_WithMatch()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(_animals.None(t => t.Name == "Pony"));
}

[TestMethod]
public void EnumerableExtensions_None()
{
    var emtpyList = new List<Animal>(); { };

    Assert.IsTrue(emtpyList.None());
}
```

As you can see in the picture, when I run a Code Coverage Analysis, the delegate body is not covered (white selection), because of the deferred execution.

This question comes close to the problem:
[Code Coverage on Lambda Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701362/code-coverage-on-lambda-expressions)

But does not quite solve it: Since the List must stay empty, it's impossible to actually step into that piece of code.

I am tempted to mark the segment with [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] ...

How would you write the UnitTest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test that `None()` returns `false` when given a *non-empty* list of `Animal`. As it is, you never execute your default lambda expression.

You might even find a bug...

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. Literally thought of it at the same time. And there was a bug! I can either delete the question or leave it here for posterity... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to write the Test. Even found a bug!

```
public void EnumerableExtensions_None()
{
    // _animals HAS entries
    Assert.IsFalse(_animals.None());
}
```

Code Coverage 100%!

[image]